# How can i use array of undefiend length?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] arr;

}
```

//I'm new to java and getting problem for initializing and getting inputs from user.

Comment: Please give details, it's not understandable

Comment: This is not an array of undefined length. It is an uninitialized array, and you won't be able to use it if you don't initialize it. And initializing it will require to specify a fixed length. Java doesn't have undefined length arrays.

Comment: but even if after initialization we require specific object to put that array into it , and i have read that in java everything is an object

Comment: @Minhaj Everything but primitives. `int`, `double`, `long`, etc are primitives. everything else is object. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: okay its clearing mess now , thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Most  likely what you want is an ArrayList

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
ints.add(1);
ints.add(3);
int i = ints.get(0); // == 1
for (int x : ints) {
    System.out.println(x); // print out all values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot to create an array of undefined length.

If you need to store a number of elements, where you don't know in advance how many elements to store. Ideally, you will need to use a `List`. For example,

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Dose <Integer> belong to wrap classes ?

Comment: Yes, It is a Wrapper class for `int`. List and other collections cannot store primitives like `int` and `double` directly. So, you need to use the respecive Wrapper Classes.